# Sum and modulo 10^9+7 of elements of the vector using transform and plus<int>(). Is there any way to do like this?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, stdvector

I want to add elements of two vectors ( small value example V1={1,2,3} V2{4,5,6} then V3={5,7,9}) and also want to take modulo 10^9+7 is there any faster(than looping) way for this ??

Comment: Faster than what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambdas:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::back_inserter(v3),
               [](int x, int y) { return x + y; });
```

Or [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) instead of vectors:

```
std::valarray<int> v1 = {1,2,3};
std::valarray<int> v2 = {4,5,6};
std::valarray<int> v3 = v1 + v2; // or other arithmetics
```

Another alternative to `std::transform` is to use the [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) function.